# Filtrando resultados com selects Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

resultados

```
idRes(int)  | idEmp(int)    | data(varchar[8]) | resultado(text)
------------------------------------------------------------------
1           | 1             | 20200220         | (xml em texto)
2           | 1             | 20200221         | (xml em texto)
3           | 2             | 20200220         | (xml em texto)
```

Estou tentando buscar os ids de empresas (nesse caso, idEmp = 1) que obtiveram resultados nos dias 20/02/2020 (data = 20200220) E 21/02/2020 (data = 20200221)

Estou um pouco perdido em como faze-lo. Eu sei que

select idEmp where data in ('20200220' and '20200221')

não funciona, mas não sei como prosseguir ou corrigir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM resultados a WHERE a.data = '20200220' AND 
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM resultados b WHERE b.idEmp = a.idEmp AND b.data = '20200221');
```

Uma dúvida: se é uma data por qual motivo você não declara o campo data como `DATE`?

Comment: Não tivemos a ideia de criar o campo como date ou timestamp, e nesse formato achavamos mais facil fazer ordenação de data (20200221 vem antes de 20200220, etc). Vou testar sua sugestão.

Comment: Uma forma     select idEmp where data in ('20200220','20200221') group by idEmp having count(distinct data) = 2